# ngFor doesn't fires after update depending variable in Angular2

Tags: javascript, data-binding, angular, components, ngfor

I have 2 components: `CommandListComponent` and `CommandLineComponent`. Inside of a `CommandListComponent` template i handle a click event on a text string:

`CommandListComponent` template:

```html
<li *ngFor="#command of commandList" class="b-command-list__command"><span (click)="checkCommand(command)" class="b-command-list__text">{{command}}</span></li>
```

commandlist.component.ts

```js
import {CommandLineComponent} from "./commandline.component";

...

export class CommandListComponent {
    commandLineComponent: any;

    constructor(private _commandLine: CommandLineComponent) {
        this.commandLineComponent = _commandLine;
    }

    checkCommand(command: string): void {
        this.commandLineComponent.add(command);
    }

}
```

When `click` is fired i pass choosen command to `add` method of a `CommandLineComponent`:

```js
export class CommandLineComponent {
    commands: string[] = [];

    add(command: string): void {
        if (command) this.commands.push(command);
        console.log(this.commands);
    }
}
```

And within a template of a `CommandLineComponent` i print a list of a commands with *ngFor:

```html
<li *ngFor="#command of commands" class="b-command-textarea__command">{{command}}</li>
```

But *ngFor doesn't fires when i choose a command and `commands` array of a `CommandLineComponent` updated. So, data binding is not working. `commands` array updates successfully:

[image]

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you reference the `commandLineComponent` component. If there is a relation between them you could use the `ViewChild` decorator

```
class CommandListComponent {
  @ViewChild(CommandLineComponent)
  commandLineComponent: any;
  (...)
}
```

If not, you need to use a shared service to share the `commands` list between these two components. Something like that:

```
export class CommandService {
  commands:string[] = [];
  commandAdded:Subject<string> = new Subject();

  add(command: string): void {
    if (command) {
      this.commands.push(command);
      this.commandAdded.next(command);
    }
    console.log(this.commands);
  }
}
```

You need to define the service when bootstrapping your application and both components can inject it.

```
class CommandListComponent {
  constructor(private commandService:CommandService) {
  }
}

checkCommand(command: string): void {
    this.commandService.add(command);
}
```

The `CommandLineComponent` component will be notified of a new command like this and can update the view accordingly:

```
class CommandLineComponent {
  constructor(private commandService:CommandService) {
    this.commandService.commandAdded.subscribe(command => {
      // Update the list displayed in the component...
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I create a `CommandLineService` and send commands to it. It works great. But subscription inside `CommandLineComponent` doesn't fires: [code snippet](http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/6_5_2016/15/rLPNLhsRtEiW0coFxJ0DpA.jpg)

Comment: How do you trigger the event: `this.commandAdded.next(command);`? Do you define the `CommandLineService` when bootstrapping your application?

Comment: The code of a `CommandLinjeService` [code snippet](http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/6_5_2016/16/t3Vulwd9CkuLCKlfiV8g.jpg) where `console.log()` is fired. Do i need to add something to a boot.ts ? [code snippet of a boot.ts](http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/6_5_2016/16/3gsWdTyY4UeVIVTmyRKcow.jpg)

Comment: Maybe we need to use `Observable` instead of `Subject` ?

Comment: I would add this in the boot.ts: `bootstrap(TeamControllerComponent, [ CommandLineService]);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111233/discussion-between-edward-and-thierry-templier).